# How do I upload a .gpx file from localhost to google maps (v3) ?

Tags: google-maps, file-upload, google-maps-api-3, gpx

I'm new to the Google Maps API and I'm working on localhost.
I want to add the ability for a user to upload their .gpx file and visualize it on the Google Map.

I've found this AJAX function wich works fine when I hardcode the .gpx file, but when I try to import the file from my computer, I got a grey screen for short second which then disappears.

Any idea or solution for this problem is more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.

```
function get_file() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("file_upload"); 
    var filename = fileInput.value; 
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap(map, filename);
}

function loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap(map, filename) {
    $.ajax({url: filename,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            var parser = new GPXParser(data, map);
            parser.setTrackColour("#ff0000");     // Set the track line colour
            parser.setTrackWidth(5);            // Set the track line width
            parser.setMinTrackPointDelta(0.001);      // Set the minimum distance between track points
            parser.centerAndZoom(data);
            parser.addTrackpointsToMap();         // Add the trackpoints
            parser.addWaypointsToMap();           // Add the waypoints
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to access filesystem from JavaScript.

This is a security issue. To resolve your issue I can see only one option: You should have server-side functionality that will temporary store user uploaded data. And then you can load user defined `.gpx` files from server.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick answer!

I will proceed upload in the server side.

I'm trying now to load file from server! how come it doesn't take dynamic file name ? 
Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Hi, 

I did the server side of upload and it's working fine, now my question is how to transfert a file name from php to javascript. The only way i see for doing this is an echo to a javascript variable ? 
Is there a better way ? 

Thanks